# React HOC - Access wrapped component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
PRESENTATIONAL COMPONENT
class ClientsPage extends React.Component {

_myFunction() {
//do what needs to be done
}

render() {
return <div></div>
}
}
export default doMagic(ClientsPage)



HOC COMPONENT
export const doMagic= (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class MyMagic extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const props = Object.assign({}, this.props , {
                xxx: ???,
            });

            return <WrappedComponent { ...props } />
        }
    };
}
```

Hi guys, i have react component and want to transform it in some way in my HOC component.
But heres the problem. I want to create another prop lets call it xxx in HOC. This prop will be of type object and one of properties of this object should be function from wrapped component so womething like

xxx : {callback : **reference to function from wrapped component**}

Is this even possible ?

thx in advance

Comment: What's your use case to do this? Using this approach, you are making your HOC aware of a function present inside the wrapped component, creating a tight coupling between the two, which defeats the purpose of creating a HOC, and makes your coode error-prone. There must be a better way than this, of doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am assuming you want what Elumalai is suggesting in his answer. It will surely work but doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: My use case is this im using third party Table component which is accepting data in some format e.g array of cells with id,value,clickCallback.So in every componentwhich contains this table(basically every page in my app)  im wrapping my custom component with mentioned HOC and adding clickCallback because its implementation is different every time

Comment: I am still not sure, but is Elumalai's answer what you are looking for?

Comment: I mean yeah it works...but now after @AbhishekJain comment im not sure that this is the right approach :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do callback to wrapped component's function with WrappedComponent.prototype._myFunction()

```
const doMagic= (WrappedComponent) => {
        return class MyMagic extends React.Component {
            render() {
                const props = Object.assign({}, this.props , {
                    xxx: WrappedComponent.prototype._myFunction()
                });

                return <WrappedComponent { ...props } />
            }
        };
}

class ClientsPage extends React.Component {

        _myFunction() {
            return "Wrapped Component Function Callback Done..!";
        }

        render() {
            return <div>Hello {this.props.xxx}</div>
        }
}

export default doMagic(ClientsPage)
```

You can see the working jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/12ojjddw/

Comment: Is it possible to access props/state from _myFunction() ?

Comment: Do you mean ClientsPage's state/props?

Comment: yes exatly...i think im not able to do that as props are passed only when component is instantiated...is there a way around this ? i can think _myFunction being higher order function accepting props and returning another function but this is getting really dirty

Comment: We can't access state/props of wrapped component inside HOC. Have your tried react-redux? You can externally connect state as props to component that is something action performed in _myFunction. Hope this helps you..! Else I will help you for the exact case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access WrappedCompoent props, then you need to use Inheritance Inversion, it is a bit more complex, but allows you full control, here is a good explanation:

https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e